# do strong bonds have lower energies?

Tags: bond

I was looking at a graph of the internuclear distance vs. the potential energy, and the strongest H2 bond had the lowest potential energy.

Is this always the case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, yes, and this is not limited to bonds. The stablest *anything* has the lowest potential energy, because things just tend to find positions with lower potential energy and stay there. This is the very nature of our world.

On the other hand, in this case the energy required to get things out of this position (that is, to break the bonds, if we are talking about bonds) is the greatest.